# onclick validate file type, if the file is good send some data to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with too many fields. What I am trying to do, is first do some validation using jquery; which is working fine so far.
I have an event handler "onclik" which validate the file type that uploaded by the users, and if the file is not image shows a message to the user. If the file is good it should send some data to the server and wait for the response.
So far everything is working fine for me, but the ajax doesn't work. Please give me hand
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //$(\'#saveData\').bind(\'click\', function() {
    //$(\'#saveData\').live(\'click\', function() {
  $(\'#saveData\').click( function(){
   var ext = $("#articlePhoto").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
   var allow = new Array("gif","png","jpg","jpeg","");
   if(jQuery.inArray(ext, allow) == -1) {
    $("div.fileType").html("some error message");
    $("div.fileType").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
    return false;
   }
   else
   {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url+"somefile.php",
       data: "item1=somedata&item2=others",
       success: function(data){
         alert(data); // doesn't work
       }
     });
   }
  });
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably check the type of a file from its filename. Mac and Linux machines have other mechanisms of determining file type than extension, and even under Windows you don't have access to the file-extension-to-type mapping.

Whilst it may be appropriate to print a warning if you do not recognise the file type from its extension (eg. appearing on `change` on the file upload field), you should not block uploads when this happens.

Other than that, the `ajax()` call should work, however:

- you have some stray backslashes (I assume a copy-and-paste typo);
- you're not returning false when starting the `ajax()` request. If `#saveData` is a form submit button, that means the form will still submit on click, and that navigation would cancel the `ajax()` call;
- I don't really know what this is supposed to do:

  ```
  $("div.fileType").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
  ```

  Negative tabindexes are a non-standard IE extension; why do you want to remove the field from the tabbing sequence?

If that's not it, add a `error: function() { ... }` to the arguments to check the call is actually returning something functional, and check the JS console for errors in general.

Comment: Thanks bobince for your answer,

Comment: I have tried to use the error:function and did not return anything. The reason that I am using $("div.fileType").attr("tabindex",-1).focus(); is to focus on the "fileType" div. Since the focus doesn't work with the divs. By the way I got this line of code from jquery website. Any other suggestions will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Put a reproducable test case up somewhere? There's not anything specifically wrong with the `ajax` call itself, but we seem to be missing code (eg. where does `url` come from?). Focusing a div seems a bit meaningless, why not focus the field itself?